# Multiple Variable Groups in Azure Devops YAML pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Using the Azure Devops gui, it is very easy to scope variable groups to pipeline stages. I need to replicate this functionality in a yaml build/release pipeline but I cannot find a way to do it. Anyone found a way to do this yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Scope variable groups to pipeline stages functionality in a yaml
>   build/release pipeline

With YAML, the way to achieve that is just specify the **Variable group** at the **stage** level to let it available only to this specific stage.

For example, I have a variable group names `1122`. And 2 stages: `one` and `two`. Now, I want this variable group only available for stage `one`, which means the stage `two` should  not access its content.

See below simple sample:

```
stages:
- stage: one
  displayName: one
  variables:
  - group: 1122

  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - bash: echo $(a)


- stage: two
  displayName: two

  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - bash: echo $(a)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```yaml
parameters:
- name: stage
  displayName: Stage
  type: string
  default: Development
  values:
  - Development
  - Staging
  - NonProd

variables:
    serviceConnection: 'Your-Favourite-SC'

stages:
- stage: Deploy_Resources
  displayName: Deploy Resources
  variables:
    - group: "Somevargroupname - Release" 
    - group: "Somevargroupname - ${{ parameters.stage }}"
```

Quick and simple!

Comment: This helped me a lot! - seeing the double quotes in the group-value. It is not documented that well on MS site - especially when you just want to present a list of variable groups to choose from in the run pipeline dialog and maps this directly to a variable group with environment settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per the official documentation you can:

[image: Azure Documentation]

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml